# Input string was not in a correct format, fluent validation

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, fluentvalidation

Im trying to validate requests using the FluentValidation nuget package. I am using a winform that has several textbox fields as show in my method below. When the user clicks the confirm button the system will attempt to create a new instance of my vehicle class with the parameters of the data in the textboxes. I want to use a validation checker to see if the vehicle instance that they are creating is valid. The problem I am having is that when there is a textbox that needs to be converted to an in or decimal in order to create the instance, I get the error message `Input string was not in a correct format.` Is there a way that I can pass the int/decimal values as strings before I check validate them, then pass them back as their correct form?

Here is my button click method:

```
protected override void CheckInputFields()
{
    string registration = textBoxRegistrationNumber.Text;
    string make = textBoxMake.Text;
    string model = textBoxModel.Text;
    string year = textBoxYear.Text;
    string cost = textBoxHireCost.Text;

    ValidationAddVehicle validator = new ValidationAddVehicle();

    //The issue is here. When the cost or year fields are empty, it cant convert them to decimal/int.
    //Which means that the validation checker cannot do the .NotEmpty() method
    ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(Vehicle.New(registration, make, model, Convert.ToDecimal(cost), Convert.ToInt32(year)));

    if (results.IsValid == false)
    {
        foreach (ValidationFailure error in results.Errors)
            MessageBox.Show($"{error.PropertyName} : {error.ErrorMessage}");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Success");
        return;
    }
}
```

Here is my method for creating a vehicle:

```
    public static Vehicle New(string registration, string make, string model, decimal cost, int year)
    {
        return new Vehicle
        {
            Registration = registration,
            Model = model,
            Make = make,
            Year = year,
            Cost = cost
        };
    }
```

And here is my validation checker:

```
public class ValidationAddVehicle : AbstractValidator<Vehicle>
{
    public ValidationAddVehicle()
    {
        //Registration
        RuleFor(v => v.Registration)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} is empty")
            .Length(2, 10).WithMessage("Length ({TotalLength}) of {PropertyName} is invalid")
            .Must(IsValidRegistration).WithMessage("{PropertyName} contains invalid characters")
            .Must(Exists).WithMessage("{PropertyName} already exists");

        //Make
        RuleFor(v => v.Make)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} is empty")
            .Length(1, 50).WithMessage("Length ({TotalLength}) of {PropertyName} is invalid")
            .Must(IsValidMake).WithMessage("{PropertyName} contains invalid characters");

        //Model
        RuleFor(v => v.Model)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} is empty")
            .Length(1, 50).WithMessage("Length ({TotalLength}) of {PropertyName} is invalid")
            .Must(IsValidModel).WithMessage("{PropertyName} contains invalid characters");


        //Cost
        RuleFor(v => v.Cost)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} is empty")
            .Must(IsValidCost).WithMessage("{PropertyName} contains invalid characters")
            .Must(CostValue).WithMessage("{PropertyName} must be greater than zero");

        //Year
        RuleFor(v => v.Year)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} is empty")
            .Must(IsValidYear).WithMessage("{PropertryName} is an invalid value")
            .Must(Range).WithMessage("{PropertryName} must be between 1886 and {DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).ToString()}");
    }

    protected bool IsValidRegistration(string registration) => String.Concat(registration.Where(r => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(r))) != "" && registration.All(Char.IsLetterOrDigit);

    protected bool Exists(string registration) => !Business.VehicleList.Any(x => x.Registration == registration);

    protected bool IsValidMake(string make) => String.Concat(make.Where(m => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(m))) != "" && make.All(Char.IsLetter);

    protected bool IsValidModel(string model) => String.Concat(model.Where(m => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(m))) != "" && model.All(Char.IsLetterOrDigit);

    protected bool IsValidCost(decimal cost) => String.Concat(cost.ToString().Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))) != "" && Regex.IsMatch(cost.ToString(), @"^-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$");

    protected bool CostValue(decimal cost) => cost > 0;

    protected bool IsValidYear(int year) => String.Concat(year.ToString().Where(y => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(y))) != "" && Regex.IsMatch(year.ToString(), @"^[0-9]");

    protected bool Range(int year) => year.ToString().Length == 4 && Convert.ToDateTime($"{year},1,1") <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(1) && year >= 1886;
}
```

Is there a way that I can first pass the cost and year to the vehicle class as a string, check the validity, then convert them to their correct data types, or is there another method I could use to achieve this?

Comment: one way would be to add an extra property on the class for those sort of `YearString` and use that in your validation, though I would prefer to go with validating the textbox as the user is typing and only allow the accepted characters(numbers, commas, period... etc) and then apply your fluent validation

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way that I can pass the int/decimal values as strings
> before I check validate them, then pass them back as their correct
> form?

Sort of. [Transform](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/transform.html#transforming-values) allows you to do a conversion for validation:

```
Transform(v => v.Cost, v => Convert.ToDecimal(v)
            // validation rules
```

This won't return the converted value though and you'd probably need to use [dependent rules](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/conditions.html#dependent-rules) to make sure the conversion can be performed e.g., check for is null or white space then do the conversion.

My thoughts are to step back a sec and consider the approach. Is this a validation issue, or a model binding issue? Consider how the http request pipeline in ASP.NET handles the same scenario. The latter would treat this as a model binding error. If you took that lead you'd do those conversions before invoking FluentValidation, then you can scope your validator to a strongly typed model without this problem.

If you want to do all of that in FluentValidation - so you can get a single consolidated source of errors for the input - then it feels like you'd have an input model with string properties. Validate the input model and if the validation passes it's in good shape to map the input model to your service/data/whatever model and include the type conversions there. FluentValidation is about ensuring that a model is valid rather than validating and enriching a model.

If you want to persist with validating the strongly typed model, then you'll need to do your conversions outside of the validator.

Consider your cascade usage ([can be set at the validator/global level rather than for each rule](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/conditions.html#setting-the-cascade-mode)) and using a [custom language manager](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/localization.html#default-messages) to avoid specifying the same custom message for each validator.